# Lifecycle methods in react

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible (and is it OK) to use fat arrow functions for Lifecycle methods in React?

`componentWillMount = () => { }`

My IDE shows it is incorrect, but I saw in different application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You technically can do it but there is really no reason to do so. It may even hurt performance as it will not be included in the prototype and can therefore not be reused.

Also see [this issue in the react github repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10810) where the same question was asked.

Comment: Quite a surprise that there could be a performance hit. . I've been using arrow method syntax for `componentDidMount = async () => (await fetch()...)` much. Maybe not a good idea?

Comment: @Sung You can just do `async componentDidMount() { await fetch(/* ... */) }`. The performance penalty for arrow functions may even be neglectable as long as you do not instanciate a lot of component instances but there is also no reason to use one.

Comment: Thank you. I've been just too used to the arrow syntax (Thanks to C#) that `async componentDidMount() {...}` never came across my mind. 